# std class object values storing in a variable for further processing in loop

Tags: php, class, std

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
    [unescapedUrl] => http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1536048/
    [url] => http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1536048/
    [visibleUrl] => www.imdb.com
    [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:WoifaIygcOQJ:www.imdb.com
    [title] => W.E. (2011) - IMDb
    [titleNoFormatting] => W.E. (2011) - IMDb
    [content] => The affair between King Edward VIII and American divorcÃ©e Wallis Simpson, and 
a contemporary romance between a married woman and a Russian securityÂ ...
)
```

recieving these objects as key, now trying to get url, title as key and store them in the database.

```
foreach($sr as $sr1)
{
$url= $sr1->url;
...
```

gives : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
searched many pages, 
echo $sr1->url;
shows right answer but when try to save in a variable given same error.

Comment: Based on the data you provided, the `foreach` will perform [Object Iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php).

Comment: i need object iteration, as i need to store property of every object in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Is `$sr` the object you dumped above, or an array of objects, one of which is what you dumped? If the dump **IS** $sr, then your foreach() loop is pointless, and you just need `$sr->url`.

Comment: its an array of object.

Comment: While I agree this is likely the problem, in its current format, this is more of a comment than an answer.